# upgrading to latest ios sdk with ipad1 and ipad2

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0 sdk.  I have been using my ipad 1 device for testing my app (building  for ios5.0).  I also have access to my daughters ipad 2 and want to test my app with this.  The problem is when I use xcode organizer "use device for development" it says the device has software version 6.1.x and to use it I would need to upgrade to the latest version of IOS/xcode.

So my question is, what does this mean for testing on my ipad 1?  Will I lose support for ios5.0?  I'm afraid to download and install, for fear that I will lose this and won't be able to go back.

FYI, currently in xcode I can deploy to targets using 4.3, 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0.  Can anyone with the latest xcode/ios tell me what's available in the deployment target drop down?

Sorry for the lame question...please don't flame me : )

Comment: is what jailbroken?  I have actual legitimate devices with apple software installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in left-up side of screen select xcode>preference>download and see their SDK version iOS 6.0.1 available if not than you have to upgrade your xcode to xcode 4.6 and than you can redownload previous SDK from xcode>preference>download.

See here i have xcode 4.6 and supporting SDK from 4.3,5.0,5.1,6.0, and 6.1

[image]

[image]